# How to connect to a local SQL Server Express database from a Docker-Composed C# application?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, connection-string, sql-server-express

Original (which works fine) docker file which connects to a SQL Server database in Azure looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my.service:
    build:
        dockerfile: Test/Test/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - MyDatabase__ConnectionString=Server=tcp:xxx.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=my-catalog;User ID=SA@dbs;Password='xxx';Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30
```

What should the "MyDatabase__ConnectionString" be if I want to connect to my local SQL Server Express?

I tried these options, but none work?

- `tcp:host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;***`
- `tcp:host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS;***`
- `tcp:localhost\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;***`
- `host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;***`
- `host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS;***`
- `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;***`

Also note that TCP is enabled for my local SQL Server Express:

[image: TCP is enabled]

Comment: Leave off `\SQLEXPRESS`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By following this [blog-post](https://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2018/06/10/connecting-to-local-or-remote-sql-server-from-docker-container/) I could get it working.

See the steps below:

**1]**
Make sure that TCP is enabled, and '*Listen All is set to Yes*' for this SQLExpress instance:
[image]

**2]**
Define a (free) fixed custom port on which the SQLExpress instance should listen on (e.g. 49172)
[image]

**3]**
Make sure that the Firewall on Windows allows local connections to this port:
[image]

**4]**
Now change the connection-string to this.

```
Server=host.docker.internal,49172;Initial Catalog=Initial Catalog=my-catalog;***
```

In this example the `host.docker.internal` is used, which automatically resolves this the Docker internal (nat) ip-address.
In my case this was this:
[image]

(However you don't need to use this ip-address if you just use `host.docker.internal`)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same things but didn't manage to make it work. Instead I run sqlserver in docker too. Then you can:

- Connect to sqlserver from another docker container:
  `Server=host.docker.internal,1434;Database=UsersDb;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd12345!!`
- Connect from the host machine
  `Server=127.0.0.1,1434;Database=UsersDb;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd12345!!`

Comment: For reference, use the following commands to get your Dockerized SQL Server up and running:

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=superSecurePassword" -p 1434:1433 --name myprojectdb -h mssqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest